# Phantom unaccept appearing just before accept

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

My answer was accepted for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46960991/52738), but my reputation log shows something weird:

[image]

An unacceptance appears before the acceptance, and they both have the exact same timestamp. My answer *wasn't* accepted to begin with, so it couldn't have possibly been unaccepted first.

Comment: Worth noting that this is in your history from [October 26th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice?tab=reputation), not "today" as your screen shot would imply. I'm guessing you took the screenshot a few days ago and just got around to asking this.

Comment: @Catija: Yeah, I gave it a little time to see if it would resolve itself when the day was over, but no such luck. Also flagged for mod attention but nothing happened yet. It still looks the same today.

Comment: Yeah, the mods wouldn't be able to do much about it... it'd require staff. It's possible that the SO mods passed it along to the CMs/team/devs etc but they'll certainly see it here, too.

Comment: Just a glitch from the user hitting the accept mark twice at the same time. The series of events was accept, then 30 seconds later an unaccept and accept at exactly the same time. It messed up your reputation history, but a recalc will fix it whenever it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) mentions in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302690/phantom-unaccept-appearing-just-before-accept/302732#comment984457_302690):

> Just a glitch from the user hitting the accept mark twice at the same time. The series of events was accept, then 30 seconds later an unaccept and accept at exactly the same time. It messed up your reputation history, but a recalc will fix it whenever it runs.